# Electric Force in Feynman Lectures On Physics

Tags: electric-fields

I have been reading the Feynman lectures on physics and I'm stuck on Chapter 12-4 which is about Fields. It states that the force between 2 charged particles is:
$$F = (const)\frac {q_1q_2}{r^2}$$
But a few lines later in Eq. 12.2, it is:
$$\mathbf F = \frac {q_1q_2\mathbf r}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3}$$
I don't understand why we have the bold r in the second equation. Could this be a vector? A chapter before Feynman said that we denote a vector by a bold character in type and that a vector can be another vector multiplied by a constant which here would be: $q_1q_2/r^2$.

Comment: Yes, the bold **r** is a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation uses only scalars, quantities without direction. It's a scalar equation. If you input the charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ and the distance $r$ between them, you get the magnitude of the force $F$.

The second equation is indeed a vector equation. It gives you the same thing you found with the first equation *plus the direction of the force*. That's why vectors are useful. The quantities in bold ($\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf r$) are vectors. The constant he referenced in the scalar equation is just $$\mathbf (Constant) = \frac {1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$$ in this vector equation. Notice how this differs from what you said: you included $r^2$ in what you thought was the constant. $r^2$ is a variable, not a constant.

Now what's with that ${\mathbf r}/{r^3}$ business? Funny enough, I remember struggling with this exact same question years ago when I first read this lecture. It's actually pretty simple.

You can rewrite this equation as

$$\frac {q_1q_2\mathbf r}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^3} = \frac {q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2} \frac {\mathbf r}{r}$$

Focus on the right side of this equation. The first part

$$\frac {q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$$

is the magnitude of the force, which you can find with the scalar equation. The second part

$$\frac {\mathbf r}{r}$$

is just what's called a unit vector! When you divide a vector by its magnitude, you get a little unit vector pointing in the same direction as the original vector. The role of this unit vector on the right side of the equation is just to give a direction to the magnitude of the force you calculated with the scalars.

Answer (score 2):

If you've never used vectors before, I suggest that you take a break from this book to clarify the concept.

Depending on author, country and era, vectors can be written as bold characters or with an arrow above them (or other notations, in specific fields of physics).

A vector has two characteristics: its direction (including both the line that carries it and the direction it's pointing to) and its length (also called norm).

The first formula you gave, being non-vector, describes only the *norm* of the force, also called intensity, while losing all information about direction. Probably because direction wasn't the point of the discussion then.

The second formula is more precise. Not only does it give the value of the constant, it also clarifies the direction of the vector.

$\mathbf{r}$ is traditional notation for the *vector position*. This vector's length is $r$ (not bold, just a number), which explains the change from $r^2$ to $r^3$, from the first formula to the second.

But seriously, vector is a crucial tool for anything in physics. If you're not clear about how vectors are written or how they're used in computation, you'll hit bumps on the road all the time. It's worth the time and effort to learn this.